# Detecting information from a zoom meeting with python

Tags: python, microphone, zoom-sdk

Is there any possible way of retrieving microphone data from zoom. As in return if it is being used or not(muted or not muted)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a feature is supported by Zoom API. There is a python module called [zoomus](https://github.com/prschmid/zoomus), which is simply a wrapper around zoom's REST API V1 & V2 with frequent improvements. Your intended feature is not supported at the moment but they may include it in the future.

Moreover, I also find that this particular feature can only be supported by a proprietary API since it would be impossible to use any modern technology to identify where a sound may be coming from during a video call on an arbitrary number of participants.